# How can I make the results of this search appear in a new window

Tags: html

I am an HTML newbie using the following code:

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" size="25"><a class="button" id="searchlink" href="https://www.google.com/" unselectable="on">Search</a>
```

I want to be able to input the results in the text box, hit enter and then a new tab opens up with showing the Google search results. Its the "opening in a new tab" that I am struggling with.

Comment: its target="_blank" you have to add...

Comment: Well, you can open a new tab with an `a` by setting its `target` attribute to `_blank`: `<a target="_blank" ...`  But where you're actually running into a problem is how you're doing anything with the text box value...

Answer (score 0):

1. To open a web page using anchor tag in new window 
   you have to put target attribute inside your a element which is having value '_blank' ..

[a tag w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

2.you have put anchor inside textbox which is not the way anchor works. what you can do is use some other element like span , div or other and put contenteditable atribute to true..which allows user to input and your link will also appear

[contenteditable attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)

To achieve your functionality of google search .. you have to write little javascript to redirect user to google search page with the text mentioned by user in textbox..

```
<script>
document.getElementById('anchortagid').onclick = function(){
   var texttosearch = document.getElementById('textboxid').value;
   document.getElementById('anchortagid').href = "https://www.google.com/#q="+texttosearch
}
</script>
```

i think it'll be better if you learn javascript/html with some w3schools and other beginner level learning sites..

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply, I tried using your java script, but the platform I am using is Office 365's internet facing site and it errors with "This HTML cannot be inserted because this type of content is not allowed" normally the way around this is to add the targeted domain to a white list, but this is feature is not available when using the internet facing site within O365.

Comment: i m not having idea on office 365 or internet facing site...please consider adding more tags in question related to office 365 and others and add information about platforms and domains in question....

Answer (score 0):

1) link  tag if you want to open a link in new window use **target=_blank**

```
<a target=_blank title="Google" href="http://www.google.com"> Google </a>
```

2) button input tag if you want to open a new window use button na use this **onclick = "window.open('main.php');"**

```
<input type="button" value="Google" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com');" />
```